# how to clear the ajax cache in ie

Tags: ajax, caching, jquery

I'm using jquery ajax, how to clear the cache of the ajax result?

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for $.ajax cache option? http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Answer (score 5):

If you want to bypass the cache you can add some random argument to the url:

```
var url = 'http://example.com/ajax?' + (new Date()).getTime();
```

Comment: you just invented new wheel. Congrats :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 var counter = 0;
 var counterValue = 0;

 function submitForm()
 {
       counter = counter + 1;
       counterValue = counter;
         var params = $("#DetailForm").formSerialize();
$("#DetailViewDiv").load("./shopmart/priceDetail.jsp?counterValue="+counter+"&"+params,
function(){$("#PriceTagDiv").show();});

 }
</script>
```

You add a counter for every request.
Ajax will cache the call but as the counter increments everytime, the params to load jsp will become different.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually clear the cache as it's controlled by the browser, but you can ask for the next request not to be cached by adding `cache: false` to your options.

```
$.get('/callback/', {cache: false});
```

Comment: That's a one time solution and by naming the parameter "cache" you are misguiding people that it has any special semantics.

Comment: @cburgmer, actually `cache` is a parameter of the $.ajax method in jQuery, which $.get is just a wrapper for, so this is actually the correct answer. "If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters."