# Ajax call is not working in Internet Explorer9 and Internet Explorer10

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-9

i used this function to display item page using ajax. it is working fine on Chrome.but not in internet explorer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function grabInfo(str)
    {
        if (str=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("contentDiv").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("contentDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","get_property.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

This function is returning the updated results on Chrome.But in Internet Explorer, this function returns the previous results.If i clear sessions using Ctrl+Shift+Del, system shows updated results.why is this happening?
Can you help on this?

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: you can add a bogus query string parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679197/how-to-clear-the-ajax-cache-in-ie

Comment: seems like explorer is caching, check http headers, sent by your server or provide them, i guess

Comment: @anoooooooooooooooop:error is when i update a data, get.property.php page will display the updated item.but it is showing the earlier data.but if i clear sessions, updated results will be dislayed

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer caches responses. You can either add a random value to the request URL's query string using `Math.random()` or include a response header in the server-side script.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

Comment: Two solutions: Either add this line to your get_property.php `header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store');` or append a random value to your request URL as in `xmlhttp.open("GET","get_property.php?q="+str+asdf=Math.random(),true);`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that IE caches the request, as long as query string doesn't change it returns the same response, this  can be handled by server side headers,

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

but the easiest  way is just to modify the request like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","get_property.php?q="+str+"&r="+Math.random(),true);
```

Comment: Do i have to use "r" value in my query?

Comment: this is an anti-cache parameter, it's always different so the query line is different and it never gets cached.